# Changing while and for loops in python

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to know some tips regarding how to easily change between while and for loops. I find it quite difficult to change for loops into while loops especially. I would be very thankful if you could teach me some easy ways I can interchange between the two. 
For example:

```
    for j in range(4):
        for i in range(j+1):
             print(i, end='')
    print()
```

How can I change this into a while loop? It is not really the answer I need for this example but some tips that I can apply to any other examples I run into!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic `for` loop sets values for the `start`ing value of `i`, the `stop`ing value. You can optionally set a value `step` used to increment (which defaults to 1). The stoping value is **exclusive** meaning that `i` finishes with the last value that is smaller than `stop`. A basic loop:

```
for i in range(0,10,2):
    print(i)
```

Can be transformed to a `while` loop by initializing the value, doing the increment on your own, and setting the condition explicitly:

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    print(i)
    i += 2
```

---

Generally, they relate in the following way:

```
for i in range(start, stop, step):
    # do things
```

Is similar to:

```
i = start
while i < stop:
    # do things
    i += step
```

Comment: thank you!!! this helped alot!!